# ionic nav-bar covers and hides everything at the top

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

I just ran into this problem where the header or nav-bar hides everything underneath it where it should push everything down.

Here is a photo of how it looks like:

[image]

As you can see there is a "tekstas" list item hidden underneath `nav-bar`.

Here is my code:

```html
<ion-view hide-back-button="false" has-navbar="true" title="Menu">
  <ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
      Content!
      <button ng-click="toggleLeft()">
                    Toggle Left Side Menu
                </button>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="item"> tekstas</li>
        <li class="item"> tekstas1</li>
        <li class="item"> tekstas2</li>
      </ul>
    </ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Where is your header or navbar? Please update with that as well. You probably will want to use an <ion-content> directive to wrap around your content, which automatically positions the main content based on if a header or navbar is present.

Comment: I fixed it completely. My nav-bar was in index page I deleted it from there and added individually into seperate pages, where I needed it. In this page I added nav-bar inside <ion-side-menu-content> tag. Right now I believe it runs smooth

Comment: can you please post your working example? i have the same exact problem with buttons being covered by the header

Comment: Still waiting on an official fix or reasoning for this bug. I've got it right out of the box from Ionic Creator.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to wrap your list with `<ion-content class="has-header">`

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item"> tekstas</li>
    <li class="item"> tekstas1</li>
    <li class="item"> tekstas2</li>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```